# React: Why would I still get the unique key prop warning if I implemented the fix?

Tags: reactjs

So I have added the fix to the unique key prop warning:

```
import React from 'react';
import VideoItem from './VideoItem';

const VideoList = ({ videos, onVideoSelect }) => {
  const renderedList = videos.map((video) => {
    return (
      <VideoItem
        key={video.id.videoId}
        onVideoSelect={onVideoSelect}
        video={video} />
    );
  });

  return <div className="ui relaxed divided list">{renderedList}</div>;
};

export default VideoList;
```

What am I missing or not seeing? I still get the error.

Comment: Isn't your `key` `undefined`?

Comment: @t3__rry, I am not getting undefined anywhere. `video.id.videoId` is how I am pulling in each individual video and that works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good. Most likely your source has duplicated ids. Print them out and check.

Comment: You were right. I tried other video topics and did not get that issue. Source having duplicated ids, interesting, that was a first for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel, I think you are getting the unique key error still because, may be the key you returning having similar id's -

You can try somthing like this -

```
import React from 'react';
import VideoItem from './VideoItem';

const VideoList = ({ videos, onVideoSelect }) => {
  const renderedList = videos.map((video, index) => {
    return (
      <VideoItem
        key={video.id.videoId+index}
        onVideoSelect={onVideoSelect}
        video={video} />
    );
  });

  return <div className="ui relaxed divided list">{renderedList}</div>;
};

export default VideoList;
```